# Drupal Views : Cumulative filtering from an exposed tag cloud

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

Sorry for this newbie question... 
I hope you can help.

I need to set up a search result page, with a tag cloud as a filter. 
If user select one tag (termX), the matching rows are being displayed. 
He could refine his search by clicking on a second tag, to refine it even more (displaying results matching termX AND termY).

Ideally, the selected tags in the cloud, should be visually seen as "selected".

Any idea which module should I rely on ? 
Do I need to go through a custom development instead ? Any hints ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use views with exposed filters. You can set filter criteria to "exposed" so the user can choose which filter he would like to have. With the module "Better exposed filters" you have the possibility to format for example a select list as links.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your quick answer, 
Unfortunately, that's not what I am looking for. 

With your solution, the tag choices are displayed in a combo, or in checkboxes if you implement the "Better Exposed filters". 

As I said (or meant to), I would like to keep the "Tags" into a cloud display instead.

Comment: OK, so you could hide the exposed form (move to block) so you dont loose the possibility to filter this view. So you can still send parameters to the view from any link.

Comment: Hi again Lance,

Thank you again, but I found out a solution in the meantime.  

I made a custom developement, using an overriding MYTHEME_tagadelic_weighted() in template.php. 

My code is quite convoluted, but basically, I check if there are any parameter in the url, add them to the existing tag url (for the next click), and also add some CSS (when already selected). 

I will reward you with a karma for your help anyway.

Answer (score -1):

All though the question is old. This answer might help someone else who is looking for a solution 
[Tagadelic filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/tagadelic_filters)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.